# Question about Working of a Carnot engine?

Tags: thermodynamics

In step 2 of the cycle in the carnot engine, why does the heat transfer occurs from hot reservoir to the system , even though both system and hot reservoir are at same temperature ? [image]

Comment: Please check this out: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209588/how-is-isothermal-expansion-compression-physically-possible-when-it-assumes-heat?rq=1

Comment: @SayanMandal Thank you

Comment: @SayanMandal The link actually doesn't answer the question. Not only that, it talks about the fluid undergoing a phase transition during the isothermal expansion, which is  not how the basic Carnot cycle works. What's more, in a phase transition both the temperature and pressure are constant. The pressure in the isothermal expansion (and compression) changes.

Comment: @BobD -- Sorry, my bad. I think I misunderstood the answer in that post. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the link given by @Sayan Mandal, the cycle diagram does not show a Carnot cycle for a two phase (liquid-gas) working fluid. Phase transition generally occurs at both constant temperature *and constant pressure.* The pressure is not constant anywhere in this cycle. But even for a two phase Carnot cycle the answer given would not have been correct.

The answer to your question is that in Step 2 the temperature of the hot reservoir and the system are not ***exactly*** equal. The temperature of the hot reservoir is infinitesimally greater than the system. Or, $T_{res}=T_{sys}+dT$. It has to be for heat to flow. The difference, however, is so small that the system can be considered to be in thermal equilibrium with the reservoir during the entire process. But it also means the process gets carried out extremely slowly. That allows it to be considered reversible, because heat transfer over a finite temperature difference is considered irreversible.

The same applies to Step 4 except that in this case the temperature of the cold reservoir is infinitesimally lower than the system temperature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.